# The equation of the location of L1

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, celestial-mechanics

On http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point#L1 it says that the location of L1 can be determined as

$\frac{M_1}{(R-r)^2}=\frac{M_2}{r^2}+\left(\frac{M_1}{M_1+M_2}R-r\right)\frac{M_1+M_2}{R^3}$,

but how can I deduce this equation myself? From which equations is this derived?

Comment: See [this PDF](http://www.physics.montana.edu/faculty/cornish/lagrange.pdf) for how to derive the positions of the Lagrange points.